# How do I finish a main quest when I have to protect a settlement quest keep showing up?

Tags: fallout-4

So basically I am several hours already in Fallout 4 vanilla, over level 200, have too many legendary weapons and armor to count, modded everything and collected all the magazines and bobbleheads. I have just begun the main quest for the Institute.  I have not yet betrayed the Railroad. The BOS are still at the airport but I have become hostile to them.

I am currently at the point where I am pissed due to me having to do a sidequest to protect a settlement, save a kidnapped settler and remove some raiders/gunners/super mutants sometimes protect from BOS.  I can maybe do part of the main quest afterwards and another sidequest pops up.

How do I stop the sidequest from popping up while doing the main quest?

Do I need to turn off Freedom Radio?

Do I ignore them?

Comment: There are console commands on PC that might help. The [wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_console_commands#Quests) should provide you with the proper commands to use and quest ID needed. Do make a hard save before though, for safety.

Comment: I actually found a sort of loophole.  I got a quest that directed me to Preston after I delivered it to the quest giver.  I did not go to Preston.  I am now deep into the Railroad quest to take down the BOS without a radiant quest popping up at all.  I wonder how long I can keep this going.

Comment: Be careful what you ask for. If you ignore them and go beat the game, after that what's the point? 200 hours in, that's about the only thing still happening... But honestly it's time to beat the game and stop playing *vanilla* Fallout.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply ignore those: they are repeatable events and nothing serious could happen if you fail them. For example, see [Defend settlement quests](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Defend):

> Failing to provide assistance can result in damaged defense equipment, generators, crops, and/or a loss of settlers.

Comment: I don't like losing settlers or having damaged stuff in the settlement.  I had this happen once in a settlement and repairing a lot of stuff cost me a pretty penny and a lot of time looking for resources.

Comment: The game continues when you finish the main quest. You can always and will always be able to keep protecting settlements

Answer (score 4):

The chances of a raid are a function of your "Defense" stat at the settlement.  There is a loading screen message that advises you to build so much defense per every food and water generated, but IIRC that is just a 'minimum suggested' guideline - having a much higher defense will continue to reduce the chances of a raid (I wish I had a link for this, but I can't remember where I read it).

If your that deep into the end game, just craft a bunch of turrets or other defenses and put them everywhere.